# Smack API, connect() exception

Tags: xmpp, smack, eofexception

I'm trying to connect to my company XMPPServer and get the following exception:

```
java.io.EOFException: input contained no data
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.fillBuf(MXParser.java:3003)
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.more(MXParser.java:3046)
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.parseProlog(MXParser.java:1410)
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1395)
at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1093)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.parsePackets(PacketReader.java:325)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader.access$000(PacketReader.java:43)
at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$1.run(PacketReader.java:70)
```

My code is really basic...

```
System.setProperty("smack.debugEnabled", "true");
XMPPConnection.DEBUG_ENABLED = true;
ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("xxx", 5223);
config.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.enabled);
config.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
config.setCompressionEnabled(false);
XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
connection.connect();
```

What am I doing wrong?
The "Raw Sent Packets" from the Smack Debug window seem to display the right xml flow:

```
<stream:stream to="xxx" xmlns="jabber:client" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" version="1.0">
<presence id="3347O-0" type="unavailable"></presence>
</stream:stream>
```

---- UPDATE ----

I found the issue.
For SSL connection the following code is needed:

```
config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.enabled);
config.setSocketFactory(new DummySSLSocketFactory());
```

The DummySSLSocketFactory class can be found in Spark or directly here:

http://svn.igniterealtime.org/svn/repos/spark/trunk/src/java/org/jivesoftware/spark/util/DummySSLSocketFactory.java

Comment: If you found a solution to your problem, post it as answer and not as update to your question.

Comment: It's because I found the solution to my problem in less than 8 hours... It did not allow me to post the answer right away.

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue.
For SSL connection the following code is needed:

```
config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.enabled);
config.setSocketFactory(new DummySSLSocketFactory());
```

You can use the [DummySSL class](http://svn.igniterealtime.org/svn/repos/spark/trunk/src/java/org/jivesoftware/spark/util/DummySSLSocketFactory.java), which can also be found in Spark.